# Should we make an [io-game] or [internet-broswer-game] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

Previously in my last question, I asked about if we can ask questions about `.io` games. There are hundreds of these games, and we have a few `.io` tags now:

[slither.io](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slither.io)
[moomoo.io](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moomoo.io)
[mope.io](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mope.io)
[agar.io](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agar.io)

I think should just make **one tag** called [io-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/io-games) because it would take too long and would be practically impossible making tags for each `.io` game. ***Or*** we could use that tag if the `.io` game doesn't yet have a tag.

Or maybe we could make a tag like [internet-broswer-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-broswer-game) for games that arent strictly *.io* but that you play on the *internet*.

What do you think?

***EDIT:***

You could use per example the [pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc) for games that aren't here yet, but that would be too vast for such a tag on a specific game.

Comment: "Practically impossible" - not really. Anyone with a certain amount of rep can create tags, or people can tag their question with something like [tag:PC] and then flag/comment asking for the proper tag to be created, if they're not able to create it

Comment: Think of tags as "areas of expertise". If a person is a really good (or 'expert') slither.io player, that doesn't automatically mean they are also an expert at 'moomoo.io' or any other '.io' games - the games are different. A combined broad tag adds little value in this sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  We answer questions that are specific to each game.  There's no need for [internet-browser-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-browser-game) because it doesn't offer anything of value.

If it's a new game, use the closest tag possible.  Someone will come along to edit the actual game tag into it soon enough.